# How to show jquery-upload thumbnails through Ember

Tags: ember.js, jquery-file-upload

when jquery-file-upload processes images to thumbnails, it does not show them correctly when I use Ember to render view. There is either an empty canvas shown or Ember tries to fetch blob:http that is not found.

So when jquery-upload has processed image resize and calls **on('fileuploadprocessdone')**

```
App.VideosNewView = Ember.View.extend(
  didInsertElement: ->
    self = this
    $("#fileupload").fileupload(
      dataType: "json"
      autoUpload: false
      previewCanvas: false
    ).on('fileuploadprocessdone', (e, data) ->
      console.log "DONE"
      file = data.files[0]
      self.get('controller').set('addFile', file);
   )
)
```

the corresponding file is added to file-array in EmberController:

```
App.VideosNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(
  files: []

  actions:
    addFile: (file) ->
      @files.pushObject file
)
```

and the template gets updated:

```
{{#each file in files}}
  {{{file.preview.outerHTML}}}
{{/each}}
```

Depending on jquery-file-upload setting (previewCanvas) Ember either tries to fetch an blob:http reference that is 404 not found

```
previewCanvas: false
...

GET blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3000/8e2869ad-8e44-4701-a56c-a2ad2fdafa07 404 (Not Found)
```

or it renders an empty HTML-canvas element

```
previewCanvas: true
...

<canvas width="80" height="45"></canvas><!-- THIS DOES NOT SHOW ANYTHING -->
```

If I render these straight from jquery then everything shows correctly.

```
 .on('fileuploadprocessdone', (e, data) ->
   node = data.context.children()
   node.prepend('<br>').prepend(file.preview) if file.preview
```

I don't quite understand why these are shown correctly when inserted with jquery but not with Ember. How do I get these previews to show correctly with Ember?